# Need help with hydroponic ML to Gallon conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a feed mix in ML that is based on 1 gallon ratios.

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to do conversions down from a gallon

For example, I need 2.5ml of feed per gallon of water, however, my unit only takes 3 cups of water. How much feed would I need then for just 3 cups of water if it is 2.5ml for 1 gallon.

If you could write out the math steps involved so I could do this myself for future that would be great.

Comment: It need only dividing and multiplying...

Answer (score 1):

$$
3\text{ cups}=3\text{ cups}\times\frac{1\text{ pint}}{2\text{ cups}} \times \frac{1\text{ quart}}{2\text{ pints}}\times\frac{1\text{ gallon}}{4\text{ quarts}} = \frac 3 {16}\text{ gallons}
$$

Cups, pints, and quarts cancel from the numerator and denominator as if they were numbers.

So you need $\dfrac 3 {16}\times 2.5\text{ ml}$.

Comment: or about .46875 ml but I would round it to .5 ml as long as it is nothing volatile that needs to be precise.